# $X \subseteq M(n,\mathbb C)$ and $S:=\{x \in \mathbb C : x$ is an eigen value of some matrix in $X\}$ ; does $X$ closed implies/if $S$ is closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, metric-spaces

Let $X \subseteq M(n,\mathbb C)$ and $S:=\{x \in \mathbb C : x$ is an eigen value of some matrix in $X\}$ ; does the closed-ness of any one of $S$ or $X$ implies that the other set is also closed ?

Comment: Try this: Let $X$ be the set of matrices with determinant $1$.

Comment: So, as the other comment implies: the answer is no

Comment: @GEdgar : well , so closedness of $X$ does not imply that of $S$ , but what about closed ness of $S$ , does $S$ closed imply $X$ is closed ?

Comment: So: find a convergent sequence of $2 \times 2$ matrices, which have only eigenvalue $0$, but the limit has a nonzero eigenvalue.  (Of course the matrices do not commute.)

Comment: For the other direction, consider the set $X$ of all nonzero nilpotent matrices.